# JCenter stopped

Tags: android, maven, jcenter, androidpdfviewer

As of now, JCenter is stopped and I noticed that a lot of libraries haven't been migrated to maven.

For instance:
If we consider this library:

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
```

i changed it to

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:AndroidPdfViewer:3.1.0-beta.1'
```

as i could see that it is in Jitpack. But i still get this error:

**Could not GET 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/com/github/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/3.1.0-beta.1/AndroidPdfViewer-3.1.0-beta.1.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway**

What can I do here?

Answer (score 1):

Jcentre is having issues at the moment. Try checking [this](https://status.gradle.com)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to migrate your binaries from JCenter to Maven as Jcenter will still maintain the binaries indefinitely. To clarify, JFrog will keep JCenter as a read-only repository indefinitely. Customers and the community can continue to rely on JCenter as a reliable mirror for Java packages. Visit [this page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Bintray+Migration+Guide) for the official documentation. Jcenter seems to be having a temporary issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use one repository, the solution is to use another.

mvnrepository.com indicates that [that artifact](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.barteksc/android-pdf-viewer/3.2.0-beta.1) is available from the "Spring Lib Release" repo.